# Bug in iPad's html5 canvas drawimage() implementation?

Tags: iphone, ipad, safari, html, canvas

After some grueling debugging, I think I have found a bug in the iPad Safari's implementation of `canvas.drawImage()`. Specifically this overload:

```
void drawImage(in HTMLImageElement image, in float sx, in float sy, in float sw, in float sh, in float dx, in float dy, in float dw, in float dh);
```

When slicing an image and scaling it down, it seems that Safari sometimes forgets to slice the image and simply scales the entire image down. This happens on a random basis, but I have been able reproduce it on the iPad consistently after clearing safari's cache.  Here is the code:

```
<script>
draw = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('cc').getContext('2d');  
  var timg = new Image()
  timg.onload = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(100,100,100)';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,256,256);
    ctx.drawImage(timg, 0,0, 128, 128, 0, 0, 63,63);                
    ctx.drawImage(timg, 0,0, 128, 128, 128, 0, 65,65);              
  };
  timg.src = "http://amirshimoni.com/ipadbug1/1234.jpg";
};
</script>
<body onload="draw();">
<canvas id="cc" width="256" height="128"></canvas>
</body>
```

You can run it [here](http://amirshimoni.com/ipadbug1/test1.html) or see the output from the iPad [here](http://amirshimoni.com/ipadbug1/capture.png).

This bug doesn't seem to exist on any other browser, including desktop Safari. It also seems to go away if you refresh the page on the iPad.

Am I doing something wrong with `drawImage()`?

Can anyone figure out why this is happening, and if there are specific values that I could simply avoid so it doesn't happen... or some other workaround?

Comment: If you think you've found a bug in any software, please report it to the developer (Apple, in this case: http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/).  Bugs that get reported are bugs that get fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug seems to have been fixed in iOS 4.2. At least, I don't see it happening any more.