# Using the canvas drawImage() function on Iphone web apps

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, canvas, drawimage

I am working on a web app for the Iphone. I have a web page using a canvas on which I draw lines, arks, circles, and some images using the canvas drawImage() function. the page loads and runs fine in windows chrome, windows safari, OSX chrome, and OSX safari but not iphone safari.

It seems to stop at the drawImage() function. I've searched for information on the whether or not the Iphone supports the canvas drawImage function but can't find anything. What have I missed?

Comment: what does `typeof canvas.drawImage` return on the iPhone?

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878580/bug-in-ipads-html5-canvas-drawimage-implementation) post?

Comment: @Matt: drawImage is a function

Answer (score 5):

The problem is probably that the image hasn't loaded yet when you make the draw call.  Don't worry, this has happened to me too.  What you need to do is:

```
var image = new Image( "http://mydomain/myimage.jpg" );
image.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
}
```

Comment: es I think I'm doing that...
 
 //preload images first
 img = new Image(); 
 img.src="rotate.png";
 
  onload = function()
 {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  W = canvas.width;
  H = canvas.height;
     draw();
         ...more code.
 }

Comment: It looks like you're assigning the variable "onload" what to do when the image loads.  Replace that with "img.onload = …"

Comment: it may be better to do following as onload may trigger before you add the onload event

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
}
image.src =  "http://mydomain/myimage.jpg" ;

Same as pop850 but loading the src after adding the onload event